# Wordpress Page Not Found if Permalink Settings is Postname

Tags: permalinks, pages, htaccess, mod-rewrite

Uploaded code on staging server. in localhost everything is working well but on staging I can login to admin pabel but can not see any page on frontend. When any page is accessed it says `The requested URL /projectname/testpage was not found on this server.`.

PHP version on localhost is `5.4.3` while on staging is `5.3.3`. `mod_rewrite` is enabled on both. `.htacess` for staging site is

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projectname/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /projectname/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Its the same in localhost too. Also checked if `mod_rewrite` is enabled on staging using `apache_get_modules()` and its true.

On staging only admin panel is working and not frontend pages. Old URl's are already replaced and even if I create a new page it says not found.

`projectname/?page_id=519` works but `projectname/test/` does not

Comment: Have you changed/overrided home & site URL on the staging server? And is the `.htaccess` writable? Flush your permalinks on the server. The `RewriteBase` is most likely the issue.

Comment: Home and Site URL are changed to stagin one. `htaccess` file permission is `644`. How can I flush permalinks on server ?

Comment: Just load the Settings > Permalinks page in the admin.

Comment: Not working. Page on frontend is accessed only if permalink setting is set to `Default`. Could be some apache rewrite missing config ?

Comment: Remove the `<IfModule></IfModule>` conditional tags - if your server throws a 500 `mod_rewrite` something's not right. What's the full URL to your staging server's WordPress installation?

Comment: Removed `if` conditon from `.htaccess`, Permalink Settings set to `Post Name` and it does nto throw any 500 error. Staging URL - http://SOMEIPADDRESS/projectname/

Comment: Did you try to save and load Settings -> Permalinks page in admin?

Comment: Yes many a times, but not the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

On the staging server, in your `wp-config.php`

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://SERVER_IP/projectname' );
define( 'WP_HOME',    WP_SITEURL                     );
```

Then:

- Place an empty `.htaccess` in `/projectname`
- Load `http://SERVER_IP/projectname/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`
- Check `.htaccess` - have rewrite rules been added?

Comment: Did everything you said above and `.htaccess` code generated is `
`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projectname/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /projectname/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`
`

Comment: anytihng related to `CentOS` ?